Replace hardcoded values with actual values
I have a list like this
key_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

And another code like this
df1 = df1.set_index(['first_name', 'last_name', df1.groupby(['first_name', 'last_name']).cumcount()])

I want to replace the hardcoded values in second line with first line
df1 = df1.set_index(key_fields + df1.groupby(key_fields).cumcount())

But it's giving me error
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U10'), dtype('int64')) -> None


In Python, you can't directly concatenate a list and a Series in this way. Instead, you need to combine them correctly within the set_index function.
You can try:
df1 = df1.set_index(key_fields + [df1.groupby(key_fields).cumcount()])

As for the explanation, key_fields is a list of strings: ['first_name', 'last_name']. However, df1.groupby(key_fields).cumcount() is a Pandas Series, and you need to wrap it in a list [] to be able to concatenate it with key_fields.

When you try to join a list of column names with Series, it can create ambiguity because DataFrame.set_index does not directly support combining a list of column names with Series.
You can create one element list and pass Series from GroupBy.cumcount for join list of columns names key_fields  with Series:
print (df1)
  first_name last_name  val
0          a         s    1
1          a         s    2
2          f         c    8
3          f         c    7
4          f         c    3
5          g         b    2


out = df1.set_index(['first_name', 'last_name',
                     df1.groupby(['first_name', 'last_name']).cumcount()])
print (out)
                        val
first_name last_name       
a          s         0    1
                     1    2
f          c         0    8
                     1    7
                     2    3
g          b         0    2

key_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
out = df1.set_index(key_fields + [df1.groupby(key_fields).cumcount()])
print (out)
                        val
first_name last_name       
a          s         0    1
                     1    2
f          c         0    8
                     1    7
                     2    3
g          b         0    2


print (type(key_fields))
<class 'list'>

print (type(df1.groupby(key_fields).cumcount()))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


Some explanations would help the OP to understand the problem better instead of just copying the code.
